# Java Lucene Obtain Terms from Document object

Tags: java, lucene

I understand how to obtain the document set from a Term object, but can you go the other way around to obtain the terms/term frequencies from a Document object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible get terms from a document, but there are no easy APIs. IndexReader has a a method [getTermFreqVector](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermFreqVector%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.index.TermVectorMapper%29) where you can retrieve terms in a document. You need to build a custom [TermVectorMapper](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TermVectorMapper.html) and pass it `getTermFreqVector().` In the custom TVMapper, terms and their frequencies are collected in `map()` method. Once the `getTermFreqVector()` returns, terms can be retrieved from the custom TVMapper.

Comment: Unfortunately the assignment this is for requires using a really really old lucene version which does not have that API lol...thanks anyways...I'll have to just store this info in my own hashtable or w/e